# Prove that the Following Set of Linear Transformations is a Basis for $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am attempting to construct a proof, given the following information:

$V$ and $W$ are finite vector spaces with ordered bases $\beta=\{v_1, . . .,v_n\}$ and $\gamma=\{w_1, . . .,w_m\}$. Consider the linear transformations $T_{ij}:V\rightarrow W$ such that:

$$T_{ij}(v_k)=
\begin{cases} 
w_i & \text{if  }k=j\\
0 & \text{if }k \neq j \\\end{cases}$$

I would like to prove that the set $\{T_{ij}:1\leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n \}$ forms a basis for $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$, the vector space of all linear transformations from $V$ to $W$.

In attempting to prove linear independence of the set I made the following argument. Let:
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}T_{ij}(v_k)=T_o(v_k)$$ Where $T_o$ is the zero transformation and $v_k$ is an arbitrary vector in $V$. From the definition of $T_{ij}$ the above expression becomes:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ik}T_{ik}(v_k)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ik}w_i=\underline0_w$$ Of course, the vectors $w_i$ are linearly independent, so the coefficients $a_{ik}$ must all be zero. From here, however, I have doubts in concluding that the set of transformations $T_{ij}$ is linearly independent. In the above manipulation I have effectively shown that no matter what values I choose for the coefficients $a_{ij}$ where $j \neq k$ I can still make the original linear combination sum to zero as long as I choose each $a_{ik}=0$, which would actually prove that the set is linearly dependent.

Where is the error in my reasoning?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1210098/721644).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $T_{ij}(v_k) = \delta_{kj} w_i$.

Show linear independence: Suppose $T=\sum_{ij} A_{ij} T_{ij} = 0$. Then
$T(v_k) = \sum_i A_{ik} w_i = 0$, and since $\gamma$ is a basis, it follows that $
A_{ik} = 0$ for all $i$. Since $k$ was arbitrary we see that all $A_{ij}$ must be zero.

Show a basis: Suppose $T$ is a linear transformation.
Define the coefficients $A_{ik}$ by $T(v_k) = \sum_i A_{ik} w_i$ (the $A_{ik}$
are unique since $\gamma$ is a basis).
Then I claim that $T = \sum_{ij} A_{ij} T_{ij}$. To see this, note that
$(T - \sum_{ij} A_{ij} T_{ij})(v_k) = T(v_k) - \sum_{ij} A_{ij} T_{ij}(v_k)$, and using the expression for $T_{ij}(v_k)$ above gives
$(T - \sum_{ij} A_{ij} T_{ij})(v_k) = T(v_k) -\sum_i A_{ik} w_i = 0$. Since
$\beta$ is a basis, it follows that $T = \sum_{ij} A_{ij} T_{ij}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I apologize for getting back so late. I'm still having trouble with the conclusion that all $A_{ij}=0$, as I mentioned in my question. I follow the whole argument which shows that $A_{ik}=0$ but I don't understand how this allows us to conclude the same for all $A_{ij}$. I understand that $k$ is arbitrary, but don't we have to show that all $A_{ij}=0$ for any $k$?

Comment: Pick $k$. Then $T(v_k) = 0$ means that $A_{1k}w_1+\cdots A_{mk} w_m = 0$. Since the $w_1,...,w_m$ are a basis, they are linearly independent and hence we have $A_{1k}=0,...,A_{mk} = 0$. Since $k$ was arbitrary, we have $A_{ij} = 0$ for **all** $i,j$.