# What is the $\dim L(X,Y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two finite-dimensional vector spaces over the same field $K$, and let $L(X,Y)$ denote the vector space of all linear operators $T \colon X \to Y$. Then what is $\dim L(X,Y)$?

My effort:

My feeling is that $\dim L(X,Y) = \dim X \cdot \dim Y$. Am I right?

Let $\dim X= n$, $\dim Y= m$. Let $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ be a basis for $X$ and let $\{b_1, \ldots, b_m \}$ be a basis for $Y$.

For each $i= 1, \ldots, m$ and $j= 1, \ldots, n$, let's define a map $T_{ij} \colon X \to Y$ as follows: 
$$T_{ij}(e_k) \colon= 
\begin{cases} 
b_i \ \ \ \mbox{ if } k=j; \\
\theta_Y \ \ \ \mbox{ if } k \neq j.
\end{cases}
$$
for $k = 1, \ldots, n$. Here $\theta_Y$ denotes the zero vector in $Y$. Assume that $T_{ij}$ is linear.

We first show that every linear operator $T \colon X \to Y$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the $T_{ij}$s.

Let $x \in X$ have the unique representation $x = \sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k e_k$, where the $\xi_k$ are scalars. Then 
$$ T_{ij}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k T_{ij}(e_k) = \xi_j b_i.$$ 
Suppose $T(e_j)= \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_{ij} b_i$ for each $j= 1, \ldots, n$. 
So, we have 
$$T(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j T(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_{ij} \xi_j b_i = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_{ij} T_{ij}(x) = \left(  \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_{ij} T_{ij} \right)(x).$$ 
Thus, $T=  \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_{ij} T_{ij}$.

The next task is to show that the $T_{ij}$ are linearly independent. 
So let's suppose that, for some choice of scalars $\alpha_{ij}$, where $i=1, \ldots, m$ and $j= 1, \ldots, n$, we have 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij} T_{ij} = \theta_{L(X,Y)},$$
where $\theta_{L(X,Y)}$ denotes the zero vector in $L(X,Y)$ (i.e. the zero map from $X$ into $Y$). 
Then, by definition, for every $x \in X$, we have 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij} T_{ij}(x) = \theta_Y, $$
the zero vector in $Y$.

In particular, for $x = e_k$, for each $k= 1, \ldots, n$, we have 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij} T_{ij}(e_k) = \theta_Y;$$ 
so
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{ik} b_i = \theta_Y $$
for each $k=1, \ldots, n$.

But the $b_i$ are linearly independent. So we can write $\alpha_{ik} = 0$ for each $i = 1, \dots, m$ and for each $k=1, \ldots, n$.

Is this argument correct?

Is the way I've used the indices the best possible way of presenting this argument? I wonder if I might have erred in consistency.

Comment: Everything looks good, your argument is correct.

Comment: The answer is perfectly alright.Just one thing u don't need to assume $T_{ij}$ are linear.Just say the definition of $T_{ij}$ extended linearly over all vectors.

Comment: @Math what is the difference between assuming that $T_{ij}$ are linear and saying that the definition of $T_{ij}$ extended linearly over all vectors? I didn't quite get your point.